# How do I install wifi driver on kali rolling distro?

Tags: wifi, kali-linux

I installed Kali Rolling distro on my pc. but while installing I skip one step which is regarding Network.The wifi driver does not show to up. How do I install it and connect to my wifi. I have:

> `08:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)`

Comment: Kali Linux is not for beginners. Use a simpler distro and learn about Linux first.

Answer (score 0):

To install the `bcm43142` wifi driver run the following command:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Run :

```
apt-get cache search linux-image
```

Install the latest `linux-image` then reboot

install the appropriate `linux-headers`.

Install the `brodcom-sta-dkms`

```
apt-get install broadcom-sta-dkms
```

Unload the conflicting driver. Load the `wl` driver:

```
modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac bcma
modprobe wl
```

[Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/wl)

`wl` is a `non-free` firmware , you should have the following url on your [`sources.list`](http://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories)

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

Comment: while using **apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') broadcom-sta-dkms** this command it shows some errors E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-amd64
E: Unable to locate package broadcom-sta-dkms